# Select single column multiple times at differents point in time

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a simple table with 4 columns - ID, Date, Category, Value.

I have 5 distinct categories that have certain values daily. I would like to select value column at different points in time and display result along with the appropriate category.

This is the code that I'm using:

```
select
Category,
case when date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) then value else 0 end as Today,
case when date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) then value else 0 end as "Month Ago",
case when date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 Year) then value else 0 end as "Year Ago"
from table
group by category
```

It's not working. I'm using mysql database but will run the query in SSRS through an ODBC connection.

Comment: It's not working is not a valid error message!

Comment: @markus-tharkun: Imagine how many question askers would be happy if it were.

Answer (score 0):

This type of query is best done with three separate queries:

```
SELECT 'Today' AS `When`, Category, value FROM `table`
  WHERE date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Month Ago' AS `When`, Category, value FROM `table`
  WHERE date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Year Ago' AS `When`, Category, value FROM `table`
  WHERE date = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your query is that, as written, the case statements need to be embedded in aggregation functions:

```
select Category,
       avg(case when date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY) then value end) as Today,
       avg(case when date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH) then value end) as "Month Ago",
       avg(case when date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 Year) then value end) as "Year Ago"
from table
group by category
```

I chose "avg" since this seems reasonable if there are multiple values and the "value" column is numeric.  You might prefer min() or max() to get other values.

Also, I removed the "else 0" clause, so you will see NULL rather than 0 when there is no value.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
SELECT
    t1.Category, t1.Value, t2.Value, t3.Value
    FROM YourTable t1
    LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable t2 ON t1.Category=t2.Category 
                                    AND Date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 Month)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN YourTable t3 ON t1.Category=t3.Category 
                                    AND Date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 Year)
    WHERE Date=DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

this assumes that you have only one row per your interval.  if you have multiple rows per interval, you need to decide which value you want to show for that interval (min, max, etc).  you then need to aggergate your multiple rows.  if this is the case the OP should provide some sample data and expected query output so testing is possible.